# Identifier userName is unresolved (not a static field) <at times>

Tags: java, google-app-engine, persistence, jdo

I am making an object persistent using JDO. I have run code numerous times. At times, i get things persisted without any error. At times, i receive the following errors.

```
 1. org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException
 2. javax.jdo.JDOUserException
```

I dont understand why it runs successfully sometimes and why it fails sometimes. These happens very randomly. 
My application is validating new User during signUp. Here goes my code.

User.java(entity being persisted)

```
 @Entity
 @PersistenceCapable

 public class User {

@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
public String userName;

@Persistent
private String name, password, city, bikeModel, age;

public User(){

}
public User(String name, String uname, String pswd, String age, String city, String bike){
    this.name=name;
    this.userName=uname;
    this.password=pswd;
    this.age=age;
    this.city=city;
    this.bikeModel=bike;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
//rest of the getters
}
```

Main servlet :

```
    //Getting SignUp form values
    String name=req.getParameter("name1");
    String uname=req.getParameter("uname1");
    String pswd=req.getParameter("pswd1");
    String age=req.getParameter("age");
    String city=req.getParameter("city");
    String bike=req.getParameter("bike");

            //PeristenceManager instance
            PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();

            //Creating instance for persistent entity class
     User newEntry=new User(name,uname,pswd,age,city,bike);

            //Query to match the userName entered in form and that of the dataStore user
    Query q = pm.newQuery(User.class);
    q.setFilter("userName == userNameParam");
    q.declareParameters("String userNameParam");
            try{
      List<User> results = (List<User>) q.execute(uname);
      if (!results.isEmpty()) {
                //if userName is found in DataStore
            resp.sendRedirect("invalidUser.html");  
      } else{
             //If userName is not found in dataStore
          pm.makePersistent(newEntry);          
          resp.sendRedirect("success.html");
          return;
      }
     }
    finally{

        System.out.println("Finally!");
    }
```

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Have any one got answer ?

Comment: I am also facing same problem.                                                 Exception message : Identifier userEmail is unresolved (not a static field) W 2015-04-22 00:28:46.398 
org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:519)
W 2015-04-22 00:28:46.398
 org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.executeWithArray(JDOQuery.java:321)

Comment: I am still facing this problem : Exception message : Identifier userEmail is unresolved (not a static field) W 2015-8-25 03:27:51.660. org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(Nucl‌​eusJDOHelper.java:519) W 2015-8-25 03:27:51.660.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same error while saving UserSession Object as JDO cannot store non-primitive datatype apart from String,Text and other Numeric Type for enhancement, using objectify we can provide key for non-primitive object and can save the same or we have to convert that object to String in my case converted Map to Sring using json.

```
Jul 08, 2017 11:50:41 AM org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer main
SEVERE: DataNucleus Enhancer completed with an error. Please review the enhancer log for full details. Some classes may have been enhanced but some caused errors
Class "net.giffy.domain.UserSession" field "map" has been defined as a Map but the key type is not specified!
org.datanucleus.metadata.InvalidMemberMetaDataException: Class "net.giffy.domain.UserSession" field "map" has been defined as a Map but the key type is not specified!
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MapMetaData.populate(MapMetaData.java:136)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.AbstractMemberMetaData.populate(AbstractMemberMetaData.java:949)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.ClassMetaData.populateMemberMetaData(ClassMetaData.java:543)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.ClassMetaData.populate(ClassMetaData.java:215)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager$1.run(MetaDataManager.java:2699)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.populateAbstractClassMetaData(MetaDataManager.java:2693)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.populateFileMetaData(MetaDataManager.java:2516)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.initialiseFileMetaDataForUse(MetaDataManager.java:1123)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.loadClasses(MetaDataManager.java:543)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.getFileMetadataForInput(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:734)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.enhance(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:525)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.main(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:1258)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhancer.execute(Enhancer.java:74)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhance.<init>(Enhance.java:71)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhance.main(Enhance.java:51)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case make sure that User class is getting enhanced everytime properly and would suggest you to declare User Class fields separately as Persistent field.

Comment: It might be helpful if you combined your two answers into one.